# Randomizing an array of string without repetitions

Tags: java, arrays, string, random

So I'm confronted to a little problem: I want to randomize an Array of Strings without any repetitions. I've already searched for such thing AND I found some "Randomising an Array without Repetitions" but all I can find is about randomising an array of `int` and it doesn't give me the results I want.

Here's my code (that i shortened just a bit to show only the useful part) so you guys can help me with the use of my own code. The array I want to randomise is the `allCommands[]` one. Anyway, here it is:

```
 Box box = Box.createVerticalBox();

        String[] allCommands = new String[]{"start", "help", "hint", "look around", "take note",
                "look under bed"};

        JLabel[] fun = new JLabel[allCommands.length];

        for(int o = 0 ; o < allCommands.length ; o++){

            fun[o] = new JLabel(allCommands[o]);

            box.add(fun[o]);

        }
```

Quick note: The `allCommands[]` array in my codes is way larger and I might get it even bigger, so I thought about a way to make the randomiser easily expandable...
I tried things like `Collection` and `ArrayList` (or something like that) and I didn't found the result I wanted.

Quick note #2: If my questions isn't very clear or you want me to add more detail about variables in my codes or something else, just tell me and I'll edit this out.

Quick note #3 (so many quick notes!): I'm kinda new to programmation. In a result, I would prefer using `for()` loops, `Arrays`, `if()` and `else if` if possible. But any way of doing a randomisation without repetitions for an array of Strings will make me happy...

All of my thanks!

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "_randomize an Array of Strings without any repetitions_". Do you mean like shuffle it? If that's the case you can use `Collections.shuffle()`;

Comment: I was asking about a randomisation that wouldn't repeat any variable (for exemple, the result of the randomisation wouldn't give "start" two times). But @Elliot Frisch already gave me a working answer, but I appreciate your interest of helping me! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to shuffle your array `allCommands` there are several ways you could. Here is one using [`Collections.shuffle()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle%28java.util.List%29) and [`Arrays.asList()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList%28T...%29) to shuffle a `List` backed by `allCommands`,  -

```
String[] allCommands = new String[] { "start",
    "help", "hint", "look around", "take note",
    "look under bed" };
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(allCommands));
Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(allCommands)); // <-- shuffles allCommands
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(allCommands));
```

Comment: I tried the <code>Collection.shuffle</code> as you said and it works. I guess that the way I used it before was incorrect, so by that, thanks to you!